# Retrofit parsing JSON response null values Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, pojo

Hi i cant work out why I am getting null values for my response. Im using Retrofit library on Android.

raw json

```
{
"images": [
{
  "image": {
    "name": "nike adver",
    "url": "http:\/\/wallpaperbarcelona.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/07\/neymar-nike-advert.jpg",
    "type": "photo"
  }
}]
}
```

// interface

```
public interface PromoImagesAPI {
@GET("/FriendsCMS/images/?type=photo&format=json")
void promoImages(Callback<ImagesObject> callback);
```

}

request function

```
private void requestNewsData(String uri) {
RestAdapter api = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ENDPOINT).build();
PromoImagesAPI restapi = api.create(PromoImagesAPI.class);

restapi.promoImages(new Callback<Images>() {

@Override
public void success(Images imageObjects, Response response) {
     System.out.println("webservice " +response.getUrl());

     for (int i = 0; i < imageObjects.images.size(); i++) {
         System.out.println("webservice " +imageObjects.getImages().get(i).getUrl());
         }
      }

 @Override
 public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
     System.out.println("webservice " + error);
        }
    });
```

}
Pojo

```
public class ImagesObject {
public List<Images> images;

public class Images {

    public String name;
    public String url;
    public String type;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

}

The thing is the amount of elements in the for loop is correct, i have tested that, the values are all null. Have i missed something, any help would be gratefully appreciated . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create your java object model and do the following to call

```
public interface PromoImagesAPI {
@GET("/FriendsCMS/images/?type=photo&format=json")
void promoImages(Callback<Images> callback);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but im still getting null values being returned.

Comment: sorry to say still null :- (

Comment: hi i have uodated the rquest function and im using the pojo you uploaded and the same api call

Comment: try changing ImagesObject to Image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79586/discussion-between-r7v-and-n4zg).

Comment: still no good, its boggled me for a good few hours ., if i add an extra item in the json, it recognises the change and increases the count so it is connecting to the API, just the values are not getting through

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I answer by agreeing. I also missed the @Expose annotation. This can happen specially when using third party tools to convert from `json` to `kotlin` or `java` classes. I also used Gson to convert from `json` when doing unit testing and everything was passing gracefully until I ran the app and everything came back with null values